# How to create a button using a macro to run a macro

Tags: vba, excel

I recorded a macro to help me run code I have written. The code itself works. However, I cannot seem to create a button that will run the code.

```
With Summary 
        .Buttons.Add(1039.8, 60.6, 66.6, 28.8).Select
        Selection.OnAction = "PERSONAL.XLSB!Clear_Error"
        Selection.Characters.Text = "Clear"
        With Selection.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=11).Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .FontStyle = "Regular"
            .Size = 11

End With
```

Summary is the worksheet.The button is created but the button itself does nothing. Also, When I tried manually assigning the macro to the button, the code still does not work. However, when I run the code, it runs smoothly.

Thanks,

G

Comment: That works for me in XL2013.

Comment: It worked for me too, you have followed the right path, but I recommend checking the clear error macro itself. Make sure you have used `sub` and not `function`. Make sure you have only one button and right click on it and check if the macro has been assigned to it at all or not

Comment: Me too, I see no reason this shouldn't work, Check your spelling, check the macro itself and avoid all `.Select`s, `.Activate`s, `ActiveSheet`s and `ActiveWorkbook`s as @K.Davis mentions.

Comment: Have you enabled macros (check at Macro Settings)? Is your file saved as .xlsx (excel 2013 and above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to first `Set` the button to a variable declared as `Button`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim Btn As Button, Summary As Worksheet
    Set Summary = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set Btn = Summary.Buttons.Add(1039.8, 60.6, 66.6, 28.8)
    With Btn
        .OnAction = "PERSONAL.XLSB!Clear_Error"
        .Characters.Text = "Clear"
        With .Characters(Start:=1, Length:=11).Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .FontStyle = "Regular"
            .Size = 11
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

I personally (as well as most of the rest of the VBA community) have a strong dislike of `.Select`, `.Selection`, `.Activate`, etc. So that's usually the first thing I try to get rid of when I help with issues, then move from there.

**Note:** I did set `Summary` to worksheet 1, so that may need to be modified for your needs.